# Is there a way to specify number of AZs to use when creating a vpc?

Tags: aws-cdk

When instantiating the vpc object within a stack using the CDK. There is a parameter max_azs which supposedly defaults to 3. However, when I create a vpc no matter what I set that number to, I only ever get 2 AZs.

```py
from aws_cdk import (
  core,
  aws_ec2 as ec2
)

app = core.App()

subnets = []
subnets.append(ec2.SubnetConfiguration(name = "public", subnet_type = ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC, cidr_mask = 20))
subnets.append(ec2.SubnetConfiguration(name = "private", subnet_type = ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE, cidr_mask = 20))
subnets.append(ec2.SubnetConfiguration(name = "isolated", subnet_type = ec2.SubnetType.ISOLATED, cidr_mask = 20))

vpc = ec2.Vpc(app, "MyVpc", subnet_configuration = subnets, max_azs = 3)

print(vpc.availability_zones)
app.synth()
```

I would expect to see 3 azs used here, but actually only ever get 2. Even if i set the value to 99, which should mean all azs.

Comment: Since I think this is a defect I also opened an issue in github. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3497

Comment: What happens when you deploy? By default aws-cdk produces environment independent stacks and because some regions only have two AZs (Canada), it defaults to 2 AZs.

Answer (score 2):

Ah yes I came across the same issue myself. What solved it for me was specifying the region and account when creating the stack.

The following examples are for typescript but I'm sure you can write the corresponding python.

```js
new MyStack(app, 'MyStack', {
  env: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    account: '1234567890',
  }
});
```

In the case of typescript you need to rebuild and synth before you deploy.

```sh
$ npm run build
$ cdk synth
```